# agora start method error : post method api body check failed

Tags: javascript, agora.io, agora-cloud-recording

I'm building a video-calling app using **Next js and agora.io 4**, I followed the steps mentioned in the Docs.

- I enabled agora cloud recording
- called the `acquire method` and got the `resourceId`.
- Then, I called the `start method`. but it always failed with an error *`post method API body check failed!`*

However, it works perfectly on **Postman**.

Here's the code :

```js
import axios from "axios";
import chalk from "chalk";

// AWS S3 storage bucket credentials
const secretKey = process.env.S3_SECRET_KEY;
const accessKey = process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY;
const bucket = process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME;
const region = process.env.S3_BUCKET_REGION;
const vendor = process.env.S3_VENDOR;

//agora credentials
const appId = process.env.APP_ID;
const key = process.env.KEY;
const secret = process.env.SECRET;

export default async function startHandler(req, res) {
    //call agora start method
    const { uid, cname, resourceId, token } = req.body;

    const plainCredential = `${key}:${secret}`;
    const encodedCredential = Buffer.from(plainCredential).toString("base64"); // Encode with base64
    const authorizationField = `Basic ${encodedCredential}`;

    const data = {
        uid,
        cname,
        clientRequest: {
            recordingConfig: {
                streamMode: "standard",
                channelType: 0,
                subscribeUidGroup: 0,
            },
            storageConfig: {
                accessKey,
                region,
                bucket,
                secretKey,
                vendor,
            },
        },
    };
    const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: authorizationField,
    };
   
    const startUrl = `https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/${appId}/cloud_recording/resourceid/${resourceId}/mode/individual/start`;
    
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(startUrl, data, {
            headers,
        });

        res.status(200).send(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.send(error);
    }
}
```

Any help/hint would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix!

- First, you may be tricked by the `uid` returned from the `agora join method`, it's returning a `Number`, surprisingly! the `start method`
  expect the `uid` to be a `string`, so don't forget to do a
  `uid.toString()`.
- In the `storageConfig` object, you should check the type of each of its attributes. each of `region` and `vendor` is expected to be of type `Number`. That said, if you're storing this info in a `.env file`, remember that `environment files` only stores `strings`. Therefore, you should convert them to  `Numbers`!

*This problem took me 2 days, so I hope this will be useful for you!*